# Align JLabel to the left of the panel in a gridbaglayout

Tags: java, swing

I have a panel in which i have specified with a grid bag layout. I basically have 1 column and 4 rows. The labels are aligned to the center by default. How do i align them to the left?

```
  private void addLabel(String name, int gridx, int gridy, int anchor ){
            gbc.gridx=gridx;
            gbc.gridy=gridy;
            JLabel label=new JLabel(name);
            gbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbag.setConstraints(label, gbc);
            panel1.add(label);
```

The caller lines are:

```
gbc=new GridBagConstraints();
        gbag=new GridBagLayout();
panlel1.setLayout(gbag);
addLabel("    Exemption type", 0, 0,anchor );
```

Comment: Additionally setting gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST worked for me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
JLabel myLabel = new JLabel("Fubar", SwingConstants.LEFT);
```

Or you could do the same on an already created JLabel by calling `myLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);`

edit: for example:

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.*;

public class GridBagExample {
   private static void createAndShowUI() {
      String[] data = {"one", "two", "three", "four"};

      JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
      GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
      gbc.gridx = 0;
      gbc.gridy = 0;
      gbc.gridwidth = 1;
      gbc.gridheight = 1;
      gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
      gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
      gbc.weightx = 1.0;  // **** comment this line out to see effect ****
      gbc.weighty = 1.0;  // **** comment this line out to see effect ****

      for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
         JLabel label = new JLabel(data[i]);
         gbc.gridy = i;
         panel.add(label, gbc);
      }

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("GridBagExample");
      frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowUI();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: I did not work. I think it has to do something with Gridbag layout

Comment: @Kaushik: if it doesn't work, then we'll need more information. Consider creating and posting a minimal compilable code example that demonstrates the problem, an [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org) (check the link).

Comment: @Kaushik: Also, do you set the GridBagConstraints.fill, anchor and GridBagConstraints.weightx properly?

Comment: I haven't set weightx.I set fill to horizontal

Comment: @Kaushik: You must set weightx and weighty, else your components will all bunch up in the center of the container. please see edit above showing code example of what I mean.

Comment: It worked. can you elaborate what weightx and weighty do. can you also explanin what does fill and anchor do?

Comment: @Kaushik: you'll find all the explanations that you'll need here: [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved this.
The important part is

```
gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
```

The above is called right after you specify the layout cell you want and right before you add the component to the panel.

> GridBagConstraints **anchor**
>
> This field is used when the component is smaller than its display
>   area. It determines where, within the display area, to place the
>   component. ...

Below is basically how I implemented it.

```
public class ControlPanel extends JPanel{...    
        ControlPanel(){
          this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
          //create components
          ...

          GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints(); 

          //space components out a little
          gbc.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);

          gbc.gridx = 0;
          gbc.gridy = 0;
          this.add(button_btn,gbc);

          gbc.gridx = 1;
          gbc.gridy = 0;
          this.add(spinner1_pnl,gbc);

          gbc.gridx = 2;
          gbc.gridy = 0;
          this.add(spinner2_pnl,gbc);

          gbc.gridx = 3;
          gbc.gridy = 0;
          this.add(checkbox1_chk,gbc);

          gbc.gridx = 4;
          gbc.gridy = 0;
          this.add(checkbox2_chk,gbc);

          gbc.gridx = 0;
          gbc.gridy = 1;
          gbc.gridwidth = 3;  //span 3 columns
          gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
          this.add(results_lbl,gbc);
        }
    }
```

In this case I put a label below some other components, but most importantly that label is left (west) aligned within its cell.